# Fixed Columns in an Android Textview

Tags: java, android, listview, textview, android-linearlayout

I am trying to build a listview in android but have four columns that are all equal. I am using `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` which does give me equal columns, until one of the fields has text greater than it's column's allotted width.

I have been trying to find a solution that would fix the weight of the column so that the extra text would ideally move to the next row.

This is my layout for the listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txvService"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:singleLine="false"/>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txvScheduleDate"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:singleLine="false" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txvQty"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:singleLine="false" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txvBalance"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:singleLine="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe singleline=false helps?

Comment: Good idea but I just placed android:singleLine="false" in all of the textviews but it does not help, it's still pushing everything over.

Comment: You might wanna check this out:
http://solvedstack.com/questions/android-textview-text-not-getting-wrapped

Comment: I'm trying your code and the extra text is moving to the next row. Columns are of the same width but different height.

Comment: I just realized that the suggestions that were given as answers to work, I just tested my code in a different layout. My issue apparently is when at run time it's placed in the listview. Which I am sure is a very different problem in itself. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add

```
android:weightSum="4"
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

to the LinearLayout opening tag just under its height attribute, it will cause the Linear Layout to allocate room for a total weight of 4 horizontally across the space allotted to it. From here, each element can have a weight of 1, which will cause each to hold 1/4 of the space. You can also use the weight/weightSum attributes to place elements with varied widths across the linear layout, ie: two elements with weights 1 and 3 would arrange the first with 1/4 of the horizontal space and the second with 3/4.

Answer (score 1):

When using a `LinearLayout` you need to add an `orientation` attribute if you more than one child. Use `android:weightSum` to proportionately divide the screen space. In your case it will be `android:weightSum=4`